# Decimation and Upsampling

Tags: fft

I'm currently trying to understand decimation and possible ways to retrieve back the original signal. If the signal of supposed frequency $X$ Hz was decimated by a factor of four, would there be $4$ distinct peaks in the decimated signal spectrum at frequencies $X/4$, $X/2$, $3X/4$, and $X$? Furthermore, would I need to upsample (interpolate between the $2$ data points) the signal by $4$ times to get back the original signal $X$ (Would the upsampled signal of the decimated signal spectrum look similar to the spectrum of $x$)?

Comment: First question: no. Second question: In general, no; if the original signal was band-limited to ¼ of the total bandwidth, yes, you'd get something equivalent. You don't seem to overly well understand the effects of decimation. If unsure, first read what the *Nyquist bandwidth* is, what *aliasing* does to your spectrum, and what you need to do to (information-)losslessly decimate.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. Yes, I'm having difficulty in understanding the processes that were apply to this signal. Looking at the spectrogram of the signal, I see four copies of both the alias and actual signals, but not all copies are of the same strength.